# Printing a class to file java / HTA

Tags: java, asp-classic, printing-web-page

I have the following HTML text:

```
<table id="items">
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Unit Cost</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item-row">
    <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Items to list</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
    <td class="description"><textarea>Details about the items</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea class="cost">value of the listed item</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea class="qty">1</textarea></td>
    <td><span class="price">amount total</span></td>
  </tr>
```

---

I would like to print the results in the table to a txt file.
I know it is  something simple that I am missing but I am not very good at this java. But I need to figure it out to use it on a project around the house.

Any help would be great

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but what you have here is not "code." It's markup.  You'll need to make some attempt at this yourself before you can expect much help.  Your "question" is much too broad to answer.

Comment: Please clarify: what is your input, what is the output you want to produce and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Check out parsing code.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.*;

public class ParseXML {

public static void main(String argv[])throws IOException {

     try {     
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("results/yourresult.txt")); 
         File fXmlFile = new File("data/yourxml.xml");  

         DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();      
         Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);      
         doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();    
         NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("md:record");     
         for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) 
         {      
             Node node = nList.item(i);    
             if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)    
             {         
                  Element eElement = (Element) node; 
                 if(eElement.hasChildNodes())    
                 {               
                     NodeList nl = node.getChildNodes();      
                     for(int j=0; j<nl.getLength(); j++)  
                     {                   
                         Node nd = nl.item(j);   
                         String name= nd.getTextContent();
                            f (name != null && !name.trim().equals(""))                                 {
                                System.out.print(name.trim()+",");   
                                //System.out.print(" ");
                                writer.write(nd.getTextContent().trim() + " ");
                            }

                     } 
                     System.out.println("");
                     writer.write("\n");
                     }        
                     } }  
         writer.close();
         } 
     catch (Exception e) {       
                     e.printStackTrace();     } } 
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement)
{        
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();  
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);       
    return nValue.getNodeValue();     
    }
```

}